# I need to generate a file from binary information in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb6, binary, database

I am writing a windows desktop application in visual basic and I need it to connect to a SQL database, take a rows unique id, and using that number generate a file from the binary data that is stored in the SQL database and save it to a file directory.

The part that is hanging me up is the creating the file from the binary SQL data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which shows how to store/generate images from sql server database: [How To Read and Write BLOB Data by Using ADO.NET with Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q309158&ID=kb;en-us;Q309158) You can use it for any type of file.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 or .net?  You have both tags but the text says only visual basic.

Possible solution:
http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BLOBinAdoDotNet04232005065613AM/BLOBinAdoDotNet.aspx